# Set click on text from model Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, model

I have an ng-click I want to set on the text from my form (dont ask me why), but I cant seem to make it work.

My code is as follows:

```
                <td ng-click="folderStructure(folder.name)">
                <a form >
                    <input show-focus="folder.rename" ng-blur="folderRename(folder)" ng-enter-blur="folderRename(folder)" type="text" ng-model="folder.name"
                        ng-disabled="!folder.rename"/>
                    </form>
                </a>
            </td>
```

Any suggestions?

Greetings,

Comment: You want set to where?

Comment: Instead of using the table data which has a defined width/height I just want the click to be possible on the text within this data.